# Solving a trigonometric function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do you solve this trigonometric equation?

> Solve the equation for solutions in the interval $[0,2 \pi)$.
>    $$\left(\cot(x) -1 \right) \left( 2 \sin(x) + \sqrt{3} \right) = 0.$$

Comment: Hint: if $a \cdot b = 0$, then $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. Solve both equations to get all solutions.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use offensive language in your user name?

Comment: The profanity in the user's display name has been removed. @I'm just some guy: Any future use of profanity will be cause for suspension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A product of two real valued quantities is zero if and only if one of the terms in the product is zero.

So, here, either
$$
\cot x-1=0
$$
or
$$
2\sin x +\sqrt 3=0.
$$
Equivalently either $\cot x=1$ or $\sin x =-\sqrt 3/2$. Can you find the solutions to these? Remember to only take solutions in $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Yep, I found the correct solution set as {pi/4, 5pi/4, 4pi/3, 5pi/3}. Thanks!